# Arduino capacitive touch sensor help

Tags: sensors

So I have been messing around with the Arduino Capsense library with the immensely helpful guide; http://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Use-Touch-Sensors-With-Arduino/  (many thanks to DangerousTim!)   using the code provided, i managed to get a relay to operate with a sensor.  It worked great and I was able to adjust the distance and sensitivity.  But when i tried adding another sensor and relay, it stopped working.  I've been trying to isolate the problem for a while now and have gotten nowhere.  I'm hoping someone can help me, here's the original code for the single sensor and relay;

```c++
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h> //change '42' to any desired pin...

long time = 0;
int state = HIGH;
boolean yes;
boolean previous = false;
int debounce = 200;
CapacitiveSensor   cs_4_2 = CapacitiveSensor(4,2);
// To add more sensors...
//CapacitiveSensor   cs_4_6 = CapacitiveSensor(4,6);        // 10M resistor       between pins 4 & 6, pin 6 is sensor pin, add a wire and or foil
//CapacitiveSensor   cs_4_8 = CapacitiveSensor(4,8);        // 10M resistor  between pins 4 & 8, pin 8 is sensor pin, add a wire and or foil

void setup()
{
    cs_4_2.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
    pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    long total1 =  cs_4_2.capacitiveSensor(30);

    if (total1 > 60){yes = true;}
    else {yes = false;}

    // to toggle the state of state
    if(yes == true && previous  == false && millis() - time>debounce){
        if(state == LOW){
            state = HIGH; }
        else state = LOW;
        time = millis();
    }

    digitalWrite(13, state);
    previous = yes;
    delay(10);
}
```

and here's the code for the two sensors and relays

```c++
#include <CapacitiveSensor.h>

int led = 13;
int led2 = 12;
long time = 0;
int state = HIGH;
long time2 = 0;
int state2 = HIGH;
boolean yes;
boolean previous = false;
boolean yes2;
boolean previous2 = false;
int debounce = 200;

CapacitiveSensor   cs_4_2 = CapacitiveSensor(4,2);        // 10M resistor  between pins 4 & 2, pin 2 is sensor pin, add a wire and or foil if desired
CapacitiveSensor   cs_5_7 = CapacitiveSensor(4,6);

void setup()
{
    cs_4_2.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);
    cs_5_7.set_CS_AutocaL_Millis(0xFFFFFFFF);  //Calibrate the sensor...
    pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
}

void loop()
{
    int total1 =  cs_4_2.capacitiveSensor(30);
    Serial.println(total1);
    int total2 =  cs_5_7.capacitiveSensor(30);

    if (total1 > 60){yes = true;}
    else {yes = false;}
    if (total2 > 60){yes2 = true;}
    else {yes2 = false;}

    // to toggle the state of state
    if(yes == true && previous  == false && millis() - time>debounce){
        if(state == LOW){
            state = HIGH;
        }
        else
            state = LOW;
        time = millis();
    }

    if(yes2 == true && previous2  == false && millis() - time2>debounce){
        if(state2 == LOW){
            state2 = HIGH;
        }
        else
            state2 = LOW;
        time2 = millis();
    }

    digitalWrite(led, state);
    previous = yes;
    digitalWrite(led2, state2);
    previous2 = yes2;
    delay(10);
}
```

Comment: Maybe you wired sensor `cs_5_7` to pins 5 and 7, as it's name misleadingly suggests...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are making a mistake initializing **cs_5_7**.

```
CapacitiveSensor   cs_4_2 = CapacitiveSensor(4,2);
CapacitiveSensor   cs_5_7 = CapacitiveSensor(4,6);
```

You are using same pin 4 for both Capacitive sensors. Try using different pins. I am quite sure that, this would help.

Comment: The [library documentation](http://www.pjrc.com/teensy/td_libs_CapacitiveSensor.html) says it's OK to share the send pin among several sensors.